# Consider a matrix $A$ with integer entries such that $a_{ij}=0$ for $i>j$ and $a_{ii}=1$ . then which of the followings are true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a matrix $A=(a_{ij})_{ n ×n }$ with integer entries such that $a_{ij}=0$ for $i>j$ and $a_{ii}=1$ for $i=1,…,n$. then which of the followings are true?

> 1. $A^{-1}$ exists and it has integer entries.
> 2. $A^{-1}$ exists and it has some entries that are not integer.
> 3. $A^{-1}$ is a polynomial of $A$ with integer coefficients.
> 4. $A^{-1}$ is not a power of $A$ unless $A$ is the identity matrix.

By the given conditions $A$ is the upper triangular matrix with diagonal elements $1$.so eigenvalues are $1$.so their product=determinant of $A =1.$ So 1 is true.
Inverse of the identity matrix is itself with has all integer entries so 2 is false.
But I have no idea about (3) and (4) can anyone help me please.

Comment: very very sorry .there is a mistake.now i correct it.

Answer (score 4):

3) **Edit:** I misread the problem statement as "the entries of $A^{-1}$ are polynomials in the entries of $A$, and gave the hint as "note that $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det A}\mathrm{adj}A$." Obviously this hint does not work with the real problem statement. Here is a corrected hint:

> Since $A$ is a triangular matrix with all diagonal entries equal to $1$, what is the characteristic polynomial of $A$? What do you get if you multiply the characteristic *equation* by $A^{-1}$ on both sides?

4) ($A^{-1}$ is definitely a power of $A$! The power is $-1$, isn't it?) If $A^{-1}=A^k$ for some nonnegative integer $k$, then $A^{k+1}=I$. Hence the polynomial $x^{k+1}-1$ annihilates $A$, i.e. the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^{k+1}-1$. Meanwhile, the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides the characteristic polynomial of $A$ (Cayley-Hamilton theorem). So, what is this minimal polynomial?

Comment: then both 3 and 4 are right.am i correct?

Comment: Yes, they are both correct.

Comment: @bibi I misread question 3 and gave a wrong hint! The statement is still true, but for a different reason. See my new edit.